# Combining tap to dismiss keyboard, keyboard avoiding view, and submit button

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a screen that has a large image with a text input and a button at the bottom. This screen essentially has three requirements:

1. When the user taps into the input, the input and button should be visible above the keyboard
2. The user should be able to tap the button to submit the text input
3. If the user taps anywhere outside of the input (including the button) the keyboard should be dismissed.

I've tried various solutions including using [`react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) but none of them work quite right. This particular library seems to eat taps, so you can't submit on the button press. Otherwise it's good.

The closest I've been able to come is by surrounding various screen elements with `<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>`. When I try to wrap the entire screen contents in `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>`, `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` stops working.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <Image source={require('./img.png')} />
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <View>
      {error}
      <Text>Search</Text>
      <TextInput
        value={this.state.search}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Text>SEARCH</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

This is the closest to a working solution, but it still has several problems. First of all, there doesn't seem to be way to add any additional height to `KeyboardAvoidingView`, so in some cases the button doesn't show above the keyboard. Second, in some cases if the screen is too tall the area underneath the button won't dismiss the keyboard on tap because there's nowhere to put a `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` to hide it.

Is there a better way to display things to the user while the keyboard is up while allowing them to tap to dismiss the keyboard and still interact with some controls?

Comment: I can't answer every part of your question, however, `TextInput` has an onBlur event that can be used to dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: @ajthyng tapping elsewhere does not trigger `onBlur`

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: you can try to use `KeyboardAwareScrollView`

Answer (score -1):

well I was able to solve this by adding

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView 
     ref="scroller"
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true} 
    >
```